# How to specify traffic percentage for every ec2 connected to ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have three EC2 instances i1, i2 and i3, and all three instances are connected to ELB, and one of the instances, **i3** is problematic, is it  possible to specify that 5% of traffic can go to instance i3, and the rest of the 95% can go as normal to the other i1, i2

Comment: It would be far better to understand why that instance is "problematic" and fix the problem.

Comment: This would be a very useful feature in general.  For example, we often tune the boxes or apply updates that we would like to expose to a subset of users before affecting everyone.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no fine-grained control** like this available.

From [How Elastic Load Balancing Works - Elastic Load Balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html):

> **Routing Algorithm**
>
> With **Application Load Balancers**, the load balancer node that receives the request evaluates the listener rules in priority order to determine which rule to apply, and then selects a target from the target group for the rule action using the round robin routing algorithm. Routing is performed independently for each target group, even when a target is registered with multiple target groups.
>
> With **Network Load Balancers**, the load balancer node that receives the connection selects a target from the target group for the default rule using a flow hash algorithm, based on the protocol, source IP address, source port, destination IP address, destination port, and TCP sequence number. The TCP connections from a client have different source ports and sequence numbers, and can be routed to different targets. Each individual TCP connection is routed to a single target for the life of the connection.
>
> With **Classic Load Balancers**, the load balancer node that receives the request selects a registered instance using the round robin routing algorithm for TCP listeners and the least outstanding requests routing algorithm for HTTP and HTTPS listeners.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can group the instances in two different stacks, and then use Route53 weighted policy to send traffic to either one or both stacks. Initially, 100% traffic is being served by one stack (Say, Blue), once everything is good, a small percentage of traffic can be sent to the Green stack by changing the weight of the Route53 record.

Answer (score 0):

The original AWS ELB (aka Classic Load Balancer these days) appeared back in 2009. But in 2016 AWS introduced their new generation of load balancers: ALB (Application Load Balancer) and NLB (Network Load Balancer).

As an alternative, you can switch to ALB that supports *weighted* target groups as described in https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-make-weighted-target-groups-for-alb/.